# scroll content in div when it exceeds div size without affecting div size

Tags: javascript

I have a div sized 60px,but my content exceeds it . Can anyone suggest a better animation for it such that when text exceeds it must scroll left till the content is fixed to div width.

Comment: Check this out http://codepen.io/SitePoint/full/ytwKo/ and main page https://www.sitepoint.com/introduction-jquery-scroll-based-animations/

Comment: Thanks pal, that was useful . Even then I could not find solution ..